# Latex change sectioning format

Tags: latex

I am using \documentclass[oneside, a4paper,12pt]{report}.

In the table of content I have:

Chapter One: Introduction

1.1 pattern classifier

1.2 supervised...

1.3 unsupervised...

---

I must change it as following( insert a dot after each numbering):
Chapter One: Introduction

1.1. pattern classifier

1.2. supervised ...

1.3. unsupervised ...

can I manage this in the latex?

Comment: 1) Is this supposed to happen everywhere or just in the TOC? 2) Are you using subsections? It is easy to change the section number format as you wish, if it is supposed to happen everywhere, but the simple change (redefining `\thesection`) makes subsection (and lower) numbers rather ugly: they get a double dot (one from the end of the section number and one from their definition); so if you don't want that you would have to redefine all those macros too (`\thesubsection` etc). I don't know how to make it happen *only* in the TOC.

Answer (score 0):

`report.cls` defines the macro `\thesection` as follows:

```
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
```

All you have to do is add a period, except that @ cannot be used as a letter outside style files. The usual quick-and-dirty workaround for this is to add this to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section.}
\makeatother
```

Note however that that will change the section number everywhere: in the TOC, in the actual section number in the text, in subsection numbers if you use subsections (the subsection numbers will have an extra period in them). See also my comment to the question for a bit more detail.